# Bone is not moving when rotating root bone

Tags: rigging

When I move/rotate the root bone, pretty much all bones move, except the " TGT_Leg L/R ". What should I do to make them move too?

File

https://pasteall.org/blend/142193547db345c5a479dc82641e31d8

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TGT_Leg are parented to CTRL_Hips which is parented to CTRL_Hips which is parented to Root, so TGT_Leg should move with Root, but they have a *Copy Location* constraint with the MCH_IK_Leg as targets, and those MCH_IK_Leg bones have no constraints and no parent, so they won't move whatever you do with Root.

Comment: @moonbots

Thanks. It's solved now. 

Any tips on the shoulder bone? I mean, when rotating the arm, it deforms a little on the armpit/rib area. I tried weight painting but it still remains. Not sure if I should give it more influence on chest/back area or not.

Comment: yes you need to click on the layer of the controller bones, shift select the mesh and switch to weight paint/subtract in order to give some corrections, we can see that the arm has a bit influence on the armpit, if it doesn't work select this part of the mesh in Edit mode and remove from the arm vertex group in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups